# AJAX presentation ideas

Tags: ajax

I'm doing a presentation at my work about AJAX and am trying to come up with ways to make it interesting, especially for the more senior programmers. I plan on explaining Ajax and then maybe showing what the actual XMLHTTPRequest code looks like. Maybe screen shots of HTTP request and response. But I'm really wanting to do something over the top and was wanting some ideas.

Comment: There's no need for so many exclamation points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about creating a chat-room with ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to get better response to NOT show XHR and instead do your demos with something cool and modern like [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) which makes ajax things downright trivial. That will get anyone new to ajax pretty excited with its potential.